# How to make an entry of Slackware into grub2

Tags: grub2, slackware, initramfs

I want to manually add the Slackware entry into the GRUB2 configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. But the problem is that there is no initrd or initramfs present in `/boot` directory of Slackware. I saw that there is some utility named `mkinitramfs` which generates the initramfs, but I don't know how to use it for a kernel which is not running and is placed at a particular folder. Can somebody please help me out in solving my problem.

Comment: I don't know slackware but an initramfs is optional depending on your kernel you may not need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Lilo is the default Slackware bootloader, although you can find a Grub package in the extra directory of your Slackware DVD.

The command that you want to use is `mkinitrd` (housed in `/sbin`). You can use the following command to make an `initrd.gz` for your bootloader:
    mkinitrd -c -k 3.2.23 -m ext3 -f ext3 -r /dev/sdb3
The exact kernel version is set by `-k`. The `mkinitrd` man page has all the documentation and there is also a helpful bit of documentation in: `/boot/README.initrd`.

Comment: Actually I didn't install lilo as well as grub during installation time, that's why i an not able to boot Slackware. Later I installed grub using one rescue disk..Can't I generate initrd for Slackware kernel by booting through rescue disk of Ubuntu.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: you can use the Slackware install disc to boot into a text-only rescue system, the start screen tells you about the parameters.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: ok ok ...i understood thanks a lot...

Comment: @pradeepchhetri Start by booting with Slackware's huge kernel. Once that is working, you can fine tune your boot to use a 'regular' kernel.